# Change marker on hover over div in google maps api 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to achieve a similar effect to the following:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_stylemap_marker.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/rollover_kml.xml

However, this uses a lot of stuff i have no idea how to use, e.g. the KML and the geoxml3.

I am therefor looking for a similiar effect using the Google maps api 3 only. I have been looking at the following, however i do not seem to be able to achieve the effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/mD9z3/

My code is the following (i have deleted all the content i have tried to achieve the effect, with a code i know  works - without the effect)

```
// JavaScript Document

var image_url = 'http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/pin_marker.png';

var image_url_hover = 'http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/pin_marker2.png';

$(document).ready(function() {

var markers = [
    ['Frederiksberg generelt, Frederiksberg', 55.677366, 12.512767],
    ['ZOO parkeringsplads og langs Roskildevej, Frederiksberg', 55.671815, 12.523510],
    ['Solbjerg Plads, bag ved CBS og Frederiksberg Centret, Frederiksberg', 55.681718, 12.530988],
    ['Refshalevej tæt på Christianshavn, København K', 55.686300, 12.612254],
    ['PH Metropol Sigurdsgade 26, København N', 55.703648, 12.554748],
    ['Esromgade, København N', 55.698693, 12.540172],
    ['Fogedmarken, København N', 55.700727, 12.554118],
    ['Fisketorvets parkeringsplads, København V', 55.661491, 12.561851],
    ['Pladsen foran Øksenhallen, København V', 55.669698, 12.561328],
    ['Kødbyen, København V', 55.668776, 12.559901],
    ['Øresund metro st., København S', 55.661892, 12.628485],
    ['Amager Strand metro st., København S', 55.656679, 12.631595],
    ['Jorisvej/Hedegaardsvej ved Femøren metro st., København S', 55.645702, 12.637906],
    ['Amager Strandvej, langs Amager Strandpark, København S', 55.652397, 12.639650],
    ['Bebyggelserne omkring Lergravsparken metro st., København S', 55.662280, 12.616417],
    ['Ved Norgesporten, tæt på Den Lille Havfrue, København Ø', 55.694202, 12.594257],
    ['Ragnhildgade, København Ø', 55.709533, 12.553666],
    ['Omkring Valby st., Valby', 55.664212, 12.514418]
];

    //var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.685361, 12.528127);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(pos);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      "http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/pin_marker.png",
      null, /* size is determined at runtime */
      null, /* origin is 0,0 */
      null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
      new google.maps.Size(20, 32)
   ); 
   marker.setIcon(pinIcon);
    }

    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(11);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    function changeMarker(marker) {
    var icon = new Google.maps.MarkerImage({ url:"http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/pin_marker2.png"});
    marker.setIcon(icon);
}

});
```

I just call the divs in the page, but i am not sure how to construct a div to achieve the above mentioned effect

Hope for some guidance.

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: "_...how to construct a div to achieve the above mentioned effect_", what effect exactly? You have mouseover on a div that changes the icons, what more?

Comment: I am glad that it seems simple for you, can you then explain it to me in a simple fashion, how this is done?

Comment: [Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mD9z3/) works for me (the blue numbered markers change to red numbered markers on mouseover of the text below as the title of the question indicates).  What isn't working?